# Why do some of my Outlook autocomplete contacts have angle brackets, and others parentheses?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, autocomplete, microsoft-outlook-2016

In Outlook, some of my Outlook contacts have angle/chevron brackets around the email address, while others have round/parentheses instead.

[image]

What does this distinction signify? Can I change it so they are uniform?

Comment: Different countries have different names for all these brackets, so I edited to broaden the audience. To a Brit, the original made little sense without the picture ;)

Comment: These are just autocomplete caches, what if we delete one of the entries by clicking 'X' next to it, and then recreate the list? Will it display the same angle/chevron brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just display names of your autocomplete entries. They can have any style of address of don't have the email at all. You can't change this in Outlook: it just stores entries "as is" from the emails you're using in your replies, etc.

But you can edit your autocomplete cache with one of the free utilities available.